# Prove simple upper and lower bounds on logarithm

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Prove or disprove that, for $x,y>1$:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \log(x y) \le \log(x + y) \le \log(x y)
$$

At first, I thought the right inequality follows since $x+y < xy$ and $\log$ is monotonically increasing, but actually this doesn't hold for all $x,y>1$.

Comment: The right inequality is obviously false if $x=y=1$, say.  Now move those values slightly to get them in range.

Comment: Use $$2\log(a) = \log(a^2), ~\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$$ and $$\log(a) \leq \log(b) \iff a \leq b.$$  The last result follows from the fact that $f(x) = \log(x) \implies f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} > 0.$  So, $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on $\Bbb{R^+}$.

Comment: Sounds like you've managed to disprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you have that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log \left( {xy} \right) = \log \left( {\sqrt {xy} } \right) \le \log \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right) \le \log \left( {x + y} \right)
$$
The inequality $$
\log \left( {\sqrt {xy} } \right) \le \log \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)
$$
follows from the fact that
$$
\sqrt {xy}  \le \frac{{x + y}}{2}
$$
for each $x>0, y>0$ and from the fact that the function t\to \log t$ is monotonically increasing. The second part of your statement is trivially false as already pointed out.